# sum nvarchar with DateTime sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sum

I have two columns as `nvarchar(5)`:

[image]

And I want sum the hour of those columns with a `datetime` column.

[image]

For example. If I want to add the `13:00` of the first row with the `1996-09-10 00:00:00` I should get: `1996-09-10 13:00:00`.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Too many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Comment: Please specify which SQL type it is. Date/string operations vary from one to another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the result to be a datetime, you can just add them and SQL Server will implicitly convert:

```
DECLARE @TESTDT datetime 
SET @TESTDT = '1996-09-10 00:00:00'

DECLARE @TESTHR nvarchar(5) 
SET @TESTHR = '13:00'

SELECT @TESTDT + ISNULL(@TESTHR,'00:00')
```

1996-09-10 13:00:00.000

If you are using datetime2, then they are incompatible:

```
DECLARE @TESTDT datetime2
SET @TESTDT = '1996-09-10 00:00:00'
DECLARE @TESTHR nvarchar(5) 
SET @TESTHR = '13:00'

SELECT @TESTDT + ISNULL(@TESTHR,'00:00')
```

Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
The data types datetime2 and nvarchar are incompatible in the add operator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
DECLARE @time nvarchar(5) = '13:00',
        @date datetime = '1996-09-10 00:00:00.000'

SELECT @date + CAST(@time as datetime)
```

Will give you:

```
1996-09-10 13:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest these...

```
Add the hours --> DATEADD(hh,LEFT(HORA_FINAL,2),DATA)
Add the minutes --> DATEADD(n,RIGHT(HORA_FINAL,2),DATA)
```

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Comment: Are you sure OP is using MS SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh -- yes -- op put it in the title, and also added a tag.

Comment: The title says sqlserver

Comment: Remember "hora_final" is a nvarchar(5). I can't use DATEADD with a nvarchar.

Comment: @talendguy - If it doesn't implicitly convert, then you can CONVERT it yourself.  E.g.: DATEADD(hh,CONVERT(int,LEFT(HORA_FINAL,2)),DATA).